# Detect empty expression passed to directive

Tags: angularjs

`ppOnDone` is an optional callback. I want to detect if it was not provided and hide some related controlls. How do I detect weather expression is empty?

```js
ppReminderCard.directive('ppAdminEditor', [
function(){
    return {
        scope: {
            ppData: '=',
            ppOnDone: '&'
        },
        controller: 'adController',
        controllerAs: 'ctrl',
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/apps/components/ppAdminEditor/ppAdminEditor.html',
        replace: true,
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to use :

```
ng-hide="!ctrl.ppOnDone"
```

Comment: It's never actual null. It's just an empty callback function.

Comment: In that case you need another flag variable or attribute or service injection

Comment: That's what I'm doing right not but it's not very elegant.

Comment: Can always pass in one config object with multiple properties instead of multiple attributes each with a single property

Answer (score 0):

Inject the `$attrs` local into your controller and test for the attribute:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('ppAdminEditor',
function(){
    return {
        scope: {
            ppData: '=',
            ppOnDone: '&'
        },
        controller: function($attrs) { console.log ($attrs);
             this.hasPpOnDone = ($attrs.ppOnDone) ? true : false;
               },
        controllerAs: 'ctrl',
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<p>{{ctrl.hasPpOnDone}}</p>',
        replace: true,
    };
});
```

The [JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Ld7wmt27/).